# Installing redis 7.0 from remi-modular repo

Tags: yum, rpm, redis, rocky-linux, dnf

This might be blatantly obvious, but I cannot install a package from the remi-modular repository, despite having added the repo file in the /etc/yum.repos.d/ and validating it.

I have attempted clearing all the repo cache on the system and also ran a makecache command using both dnf and yum. The package does appear to be present in the rpms website of Remi, however I cannot install it from the command line using dnf/yum. Here is the list of packages available in the [repo](https://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/8/modular/x86_64/repoview/redis.html)

I am attempting to do that on Rocky Linux 8 instance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled the stream you want?

To install the repository

```
# dnf install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm
# dnf install https://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-8.rpm
```

To list the available stream for the redis module

```
# dnf module list redis
CentOS Stream 8 - AppStream
Name          Stream               Profiles               Summary                                    
redis         5 [d]                common [d]             Redis persistent key-value database        
redis         6                    common [d]             Redis persistent key-value database        

Remi's Modular repository for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64
Name          Stream               Profiles               Summary                                    
redis         remi-5.0             common [d]             Redis persistent key-value database        
redis         remi-6.0             common [d]             Redis persistent key-value database        
redis         remi-6.2             common [d]             Redis persistent key-value database        
redis         remi-7.0 [e]         common [d] [i]         Redis persistent key-value database        
redis         remi-7.2             common [d]             Redis persistent key-value database        

Hint: [d]efault, [e]nabled, [x]disabled, [i]nstalled
```

Then you can install the version you want

```
# dnf module reset redis
# dnf module install redis:remi-7.0
```